# Why the User returned from FirebaseAuth sign-in methods is nullable? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

All sign-in methods from FirebaseAuth return an UserCredential containing a User that *may* be null.

I'm assuming that if the sign-in fails, the method will *throw* an error. So if it is successful, the user should **NOT** be null. Is using a null check `!` safe enough?

For clarification, I'm referring to the user that comes as a result of the sign-in, not the current user getter:

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'email', password: 'password')
        .then((credential) => credential.user!); // this user
    
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?; // not this
```

Is it possible for the User to be null even after a successful sign-in (that didn't throw)?

In my experience, I have not observed any cases where the user is null after a successful sign-in. Should I even bother doing that? And most important, if it actually can be null, how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The `credential` object inside the callback is an object of type [UserCredential](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html). This class contains a property called `user`, which is of type [User](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html). On the other hand, the [FirebaseAuth](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth-class.html) class contains a property called `currentUser` which is also of type [User](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html). So both objects are of exactly the same type.

Why is this type of object nullable? It's because a Firebase User object can be null. When a user is not authenticated, this object is indeed null. That's the reason why we check this object against nullity when we want to check if the user is authenticated or not.

It's true that when you have a successful authentication with email and password, the user object is created and cannot be null, but the general type of the object should be nullable, due to the reason mentioned earlier.